# jQuery BlockUI. Do a function after BlockUI fades out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery BlockUI plugin.

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

I want to chage some text after jQuery BlockUI fades out.

Here is my code;

```
$('#cls').click(function() {
        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 0);
        $('#status').text("Processing...");
});
```

But the text changes back even before the fade completes. I want to do it hidden, without being visible, ie the text may be changed only after the fading is complete. How can I do this?

Here is the live demo http://jsfiddle.net/yHCjF/4/

Comment: Why are you doing `setTimeout($.unblockUI, 0);` instead of `$.unblockUI()`? I'm guessing the latter is what you really want.

Comment: thanks @JanDvorak i used that because it came with the demo files

Comment: thanks @JanDvorak i used that because it came with the demo files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onUnblock` callback

```
onUnblock: function(){
    $('#status').text('Processing...');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJxvS/